# Pass additional Surfaces to ProcessCameraProvider::bindToLifecycle

Tags: android, android-camera2, android-camerax

Android Camerax Module's `ProcessCameraProvider::bindToLifecycle(LifecycleOwner lifecycleOwner, CameraSelector cameraSelector, UseCase... useCases)` doesn't offer a way to pass any additional surfaces to retrieve the captured picture.

Is there any way in Camerax to pass list of surfaces as in Camera2's `CameraDevice::createCaptureSession (List<Surface> outputs, CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback callback, Handler handler)`?

I want to pass the `Surface` attached to a `ImageReader` to `ProcessCameraProvider::bindToLifecycle` to get the captured images in the `ImageReader`.

Comment: What is your goal? CameraX does not accept standalone Surface. For capturing image, you can use the ImageCapture use case.